# How does Stack Overflow find 'Linked' questions?

Tags: discussion, linked-questions, database-design

How does Stack Overflow find 'Linked' questions? Does it store a list of links somewhere in the DB? Or does it extract them from posts/comments dynamically?

Comment: I've noticed that short links are not recognized as 'linked'

Comment: per my recent experience at Programmers, this feature was broken or changed few days ago. My "see also" / "related" / "dupe" comments that used to add questions in _Linked_ section not long time ago, don't do that anymore

Answer (score 3):

They are certainly stored in the database, and available in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) in the `PostLinks` table (for details, see the [schema documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/295232)).

When something happens to a question (like it's edited, or a comment is posted), the list of linked questions will be redetermined and stored in the database.