# Why aren't protocol relative links recognized as linked questions?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, ssl, linked-questions

Yesterday someone [edited my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/280269/revisions#spacer-36404854-6503-46fa-ac35-607d117d7f08) and converted all of my un-encrypted `http://` links to protocol relative `//`.

At first I was like *"Sweet catch!"* because I'm always getting on to our webmaster for a nasty habit they have of hard-coding insecure sources to images, js, and iframes with `src="http://...` which flat out won't work over a secure `https://` connection. (At least not without a bunch of permissive *"I understand the consequences"* clicks on behalf of the client.) So I try to use protocol relative links across the board for [a lot of reasons](https://www.eff.org/encrypt-the-web).

But then I noticed all of those linked questions I made to other SE posts disappeared from the "Linked Questions" sidebar. So to test, I [rolled back those changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/280269/revisions), and the sidebar returned.

This question is *very* closely related to [Relative links are ignored by “Linked Questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120678/321521), but I expect some more trickery is involved with host (or folder) relative links rather than protocol relative links.

It's also interesting to note that both `http://` and `https://` links are recognized as a "linked question." So my specific question is: *Why aren't protocol relative links recognized as linked questions?* But this question can be deleted if we can get an authoritative answer to [How does Stack Overflow find 'Linked' questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182014/321521)

Comment: [Related answer by a dev](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248385/152859), though missing the actual reason for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because this:

```
public static Regex GetQuestionUrlRegex()
{
    return new Regex(@"https?://" + Regex.Escape(Current.Site.BaseHostAddress) + @"(?:/q(uestions)?/(?<qid>\d+)|/a/(?<aid>\d+))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to expose source code out in the open? ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard We would [never](https://twitter.com/hashtag/stackcode?f=tweets&vertical=default&src=hash)...

Comment: @Adam touché...

Comment: Since neither my c# nor regex skills are worth a dime, can you tell me how difficult this would be to modify it to allow a blank http(s)?

Comment: Could be as simple as deleting 7 characters, but might get complicated if this is used elsewhere. Regardless, one more thing that'll have to be fixed eventually.

Comment: This regex has since changed to cover relative links. Can you please edit this with the latest regex?