# How does the "Linked" questions feature work?

Tags: support, linked-questions

When I link to another question in my post, the linked question will appear in the "Linked" list in the sidebar. Example:

[image: "Linked" list on https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353]

How does this feature work on a technical level?

When I submit a new post or edit an existing post, does Stack Exchange scan the body of the text for internal links, and add the link to a database table? For example, a database table with fields `to` and `from` containing question IDs. To render a question's page, Stack Exchange checks both the `to` and `from` fields of the table (because links are bidirectional) to create the "Linked" list. Is this how it is implemented?

Comment: I wouldn't close this as a duplicate of another general post that simply basically explains the feature. It would be nice to have a full, technical explanation as to how it works, including nuances and edge cases when an internal link won't show in the bar (e.g. HTTP links, protocol-relative links, etc.).

Comment: relevant https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280355/why-arent-protocol-relative-links-recognized-as-linked-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182014/how-does-stack-overflow-find-linked-questions/307749#307749

Comment: regex, it's always regex.

Comment: @rene Regarding your first link: as I commented there, the regex has since been changed, to not only cover relative links but also exclude HTTP links.